# Python: Range() as a dictionary value

Tags: python, dictionary, range

Let's say I have a dictionary like the following, where values are probability for each key to show up in a text.

```
   dict = {'a':0.66,'b':0.07,'c':0.04 and so on so the values of the dict sum up to one}
```

say that I want to build another dictionary that has the range of those values has value.
Since we cannot use range() with floats I have tried to first multiply all the values by 100, so they turn into int.
Suppose that we want to substitute those values with their range. So for example 'a' will get a range(0,66), 'b' range(66,73), 'c'(73,77) etc.
I have tried to do that with following loop but it doesn't work:

```
start = 0
end = 0
for k,v in dict.items():
   end+=int(v*100)
   range_dict[k]=range(start,end)
   start+=end
```

Can somebody please help me? I am going nuts figuring out what to do!

Comment: You are trying to implement a weighted random algorithm, right?

Comment: In last line it should be `start=end` not `start+=end`

Comment: @yakxxx I have tried but the loop do not go beyond two iterations and I cannot figure out the reason why..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change

```
start += end
```

to

```
start = end
```

It should work (using `xrange` here to make it more visible):

```
>>> d = {'a':0.66,'b':0.07,'c':0.04}
>>> start = 0
>>> end = 0
>>> range_dict = {}
>>> for k,v in d.items():
...    end+=int(v*100)
...    range_dict[k]=xrange(start,end)
...    start=end
... 
>>> range_dict
{'a': xrange(66), 'c': xrange(66, 70), 'b': xrange(70, 77)}
```

But if as @Satoru.Logic guessed you want a weighted random number, there are much better ways.  Eli Bendersky has a good overview of approaches in Python [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/01/22/weighted-random-generation-in-python/).

Comment: FWIW you didn't has mentioned _why_ a change from `start += end` to `start = end` is neceassary, so allow me. It's because, to be correct, the former needed to be `start += end-start`, which of course reduces to the latter.

Comment: Liked the use of xrange (to clearly illustrate) and the link to Eli Bendersky's page was extremely useful to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Stolen with pride from the Python 3.3.0 documentation:

[random - 9.6.2. Examples and Recipes](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/random.html?highlight=random#examples-and-recipes) - contains a weighted distribution algorithm.
[itertools.accumulate](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.accumulate) - contains the accumulate algorithm.

The code below is written for 2.X:

```
import random
import bisect

D = {'a':0.66,'b':0.07,'c':0.04,'d':0.20,'e':0.03}

# This function is in Python 3.2+ itertools module.
def accumulate(iterable):
    'Return running totals'
    # accumulate([1,2,3,4,5]) --> 1 3 6 10 15
    it = iter(iterable)
    total = next(it)
    yield total
    for element in it:
        total = total + element
        yield total

# Extract the weights and build a cumulative distribution.
choices, weights = zip(*D.items())
cumdist = list(accumulate(weights))

# Make 1000 random selections
L = [choices[bisect.bisect(cumdist, random.random() * cumdist[-1])]
     for _ in xrange(1000)]

# Display the results
for c in sorted(D.keys()):
    print '{} {:3d}'.format(c,L.count(c))
```

Output:

```
a 652
b  72
c  43
d 200
e  33
```